# Expanding widgets to fill the panel in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple UI in Python/Tkinter with an Entry widget, a Text widget, and two Buttons side-by-side. I'd like all the widgets to expand in width as the window expands, and the Text widget to expand in height as the window expands as well.

I've searched a whole bunch and what always comes up is assigning a non-zero weight in the grid, but I *think* I'm doing that already; but when I resize, the widgets stay centered in the grid rather than actually expanding to meet the window size.

Here's what I have now; any suggestions?

```
class EditWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.grid()

        self.subject_box = Entry(self)
        self.subject_box.insert(0, "Some text")
        self.subject_box.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=0, sticky="NSEW")

        self.content_box = Text(self)
        self.content_box.insert(END, "Other text")
        self.content_box.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=1, sticky="NSEW")

        self.done_button = Button(self)
        self.done_button["text"] = "Done (Temporary Change)"
        self.done_button["command"] = self.done
        self.done_button.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="NSEW")

        self.done_and_save_button = Button(self)
        self.done_and_save_button["text"] = "Done (Permanently Save Changes)"
        self.done_and_save_button["command"] = self.done_and_save
        self.done_and_save_button.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="NSEW")

        Grid.rowconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.master, 1, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self.master, 2, weight=1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)

    def done(self):
        self.save_changes = False
        self.master.destroy()

    def done_and_save(self):
        self.save_changes = True
        self.master.destroy()
```

Comment: Have you tried `grid_rowconfigure()` and same with column too

Comment: You have two different containers here - `self.master` (presumably a window, I can't tell because you didn't post a [mcve]) and `self` (a Frame).  Each has its own independent set of row/column configuration.  Setting all those configurations on `self.master` does no good when that isn't the parent of the widgets you want to expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets all exist inside `EditWindow`, so you need to call `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on `self`, not `self.master`. This code shouldn't do anything with `master` except use it as the master for itself. This code should also not call `self.pack()` or `self.grid()`.

The code which creates the instance of `EditWindow` needs to be responsible for calling `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. When a widget calls one of the geometry manager commands on itself, it requires that the widget knows how it is being used by the master. This limits reusability and too tightly binds the class to the code that uses the class.

Here's a complete example which has the following changes:

- removed `self.pack` from `__init__`
- removed `self.grid()` from `create_widgets`
- changed the `Grid` commands to operate on `self` rather than `self.master`
- called pack with appropriate options from the same scope that created the instance of `EditWindow`.

---

```
from tkinter import *

class EditWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.subject_box = Entry(self)
        self.subject_box.insert(0, "Some text")
        self.subject_box.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=0, sticky="NSEW")

        self.content_box = Text(self)
        self.content_box.insert(END, "Other text")
        self.content_box.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=1, sticky="NSEW")

        self.done_button = Button(self)
        self.done_button["text"] = "Done (Temporary Change)"
        self.done_button["command"] = self.done
        self.done_button.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="NSEW")

        self.done_and_save_button = Button(self)
        self.done_and_save_button["text"] = "Done (Permanently Save Changes)"
        self.done_and_save_button["command"] = self.done_and_save
        self.done_and_save_button.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="NSEW")

        Grid.rowconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self, 1, weight=1)
        Grid.rowconfigure(self, 2, weight=1)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)

    def done(self):
        self.save_changes = False
        self.master.destroy()

    def done_and_save(self):
        self.save_changes = True
        self.master.destroy()

root = Tk()
ew = EditWindow(root)
ew.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's fantastically close. I realized after that I really only want the Content box to resize vertically, but I got that to work as well.